# Forward SMS messages to Telegram

Tags: sms, telegram

I'd like to read my SMS messages without picking up my phone when I work on a laptop.
Telegram has a lot of handy bots for different things. 
Is it possible to forward SMS messages to Telegram bot?

Answer (score 1):

You can forward new SMS messages to Telegram bot.
Look at https://smsq.me

Comment: "This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in smsq.me. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN."